# Does it cost money to build and deploy an app with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I have built an app using Google Apps Script (GAS). It displays a form.  When the user submits the form, the submitted data is written to a Google docs spreadsheet. I have deployed the app using the built in *Deploy as web app* option in the GAS script builder page

[image]

What I can't seem to find out is whether it is free to build and deploy web apps using Google Apps Script, or is it the case that one needs to pay?

I did come across a paid service called Google App Engine, but I am not sure if this is relevant to Google Apps Script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Google Apps Script is a javascript cloud scripting language and it is free to use as long as you do not need higher quotas than defined here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas
If you need higher quotas than listed there - I would suggest you take into consideration to build your own Google Appengine Application for your service.

However if you did not hear about that since now you should first do some examples listed here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs - and get familiar with the Platform as a Service Google offers. It is also free of any charge as long as your application applies to the free quotas.

Important fact: Every Google Apps Script has it's own Developers Console Project assigned to it - however it is not neccessary to configure anything on the Console for App Script to work properly. You can review your assigned Appengine Project by 
using the Menu: Resources - Developers Console Project... and click on the link that looks similar to this - 
`https://console.developers.google.com/project/project-id-YOUR_PROJECT_ID`